# OnTouch method consumes click event and prevents execution in parent

Tags: android, android-view, ontouchlistener, android-event

I'm having a `FrameLayout` that has an [extended `ImageView` (github)](https://github.com/Taig/MultitouchImageView) as a child. When I set an `onClick()`-Event to the `FrameLayout` it won't be triggered. The reason appears to be the [`onTouch()` method](https://github.com/Taig/MultitouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/taig/widget/MultitouchImageView.java#L304)'s return value.

If I set the ACTION_DOWN's return value to false the event is passed along properly - but then the Multitouch functionalities break. Also running `performClick()` in the ACTION_UP event comes to nothing.

How to handle those events correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I solved the issue by manually passing the click event to the view's parents:

```
new GestureDetector( context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed( MotionEvent event )
    {
        View view = MultitouchImageView.this;

        if( !performClick() )
        {
            while( view.getParent() instanceof View )
            {
                view = (View) view.getParent();

                if( view.performClick() )
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    ... 
}
```

Doing the same thing for an occuring LongPress event. It works the way I need it but I don't like the solution..

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the parent FrameLayout to receive touches before the ImageView child.
You can do this by adding

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

to the xml of the parent.

e.g.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```